# overcoming minimum length on comments

Tags: discussion, comments, answer-length

A few situations have arisen where I need to use filler characters to make a comment. For example someone asked what browser I was using and "Fire Fox" was too short. In these situations what is normally done, is there a certain character (e.g. ellipses) used to show that space is being used up?

The problem with "......" is it may be misinterpreted as "no duh!"

Comment: Can anyone explain the down votes, is this not a legitimate question?

Comment: Downvotes on Meta are different and merely (usually) signify disagreement.  People are just saying that they disagree with the premise of your argument

Comment: Pad it with a [zero-width space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) if you must. (Note that this particular situation doesn't qualify as "must", though.)

Comment: Is it too much trouble to use the additional characters to specify the version of Firefox you're using?

Comment: I'm using Firefox.

Comment: [Firefox](http://www.www.www)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a case like this, just edit it into your question. No need to reply really. In fact, the comment asking you what browser you're using should just be deleted after the information has been edited into your question, as it is now just clutter.

Answer (score 12):

You can overcome minimum length requirements by creating complete sentences, like *"I use Firefox as my browser"*.

The minimum is quite low, and is there for good reasons.

Comment: Don't you think that's wasting space too and takes longer to read?

Comment: And filler characters don't waste space and are easier to read, are they?

Comment: @Celeritas: Wasting space? It's still one line. Are you paying for that space? Are you being charged by the character? And how much longer could it take to read? A half-second or so?

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes ... is easier to read than being wordy.

Comment: @NicolBolas I don't like reading or writing just for filler.