# Formatting characters should be ignored when considering minimum comment length

Tags: bug, comments, markdown

I've found that comments have a restriction for minimum comment length. I.e. it's impossible to post too short comments.

Yet in the same time this can be overcome with using formatting. For example, simple `Question fail` comment is too short while `_Question fail_` is not (added 2 symbols - actual length increased while comment have same content when it is displayed).

[Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181445/minimum-comment-length-counter-thinks-username-is-part-of-comment-length) is a question about `@username` in comments and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139718/overcoming-minimum-length-on-comments) - about "overcoming" minimum length, but they still aren't focused on formatting issue.

Is it a bug? Should comment length be counted without paying attention to formatting? (since we're able to show them properly, why do not count real, *meaningful* comment length - note, this has nothing to do with other special characters, like single `_` or similar, only formatting)

Comment: Don't think it's a bug, but agree that adding at least server side validation to actual final length is a good idea.

Comment: Well then people will just use zero width spaces...  I don't think there's much point in doing this.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy exactly my point :p

Comment: hi​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: ‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I think it is a bug. Not necessarily an important one, but I'm pretty sure the intent of the minimum length feature is to ensure comments have a minimal visible length, which is clearly not being achieved in all cases.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy so such things should be cough too. I.e. if some symbol 'has no length' is shouldn't be counted in comment length.

Comment: @DavidX.Random great, you even caused your display name here to get reversed! http://i.stack.imgur.com/WTdGr.png

Comment: @sha yeah this is because of the right to left character! `&#8238;`

Comment: @HugoDozois nasty character!